# Using mysql MAX() with PHP fetching data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problems here.
I tried fetching a data from column(which datatype is float) with the highest number and displays it. But it only shows the count of row(which is 1)

how to I get the exact 'Number' that I need?

PHP

```
   <?php
    $sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(payment_price) FROM client_record WHERE payment_status ='Settled'");
    $row = (int)mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    echo $row;

   ?>
```

What it shows:

```
 1
```

What I need to see:

```
 //the exact price that MAX() fetched
 20,000
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` __fetches array__. What do you expect when you cast `array` to `int`?

Comment: it shows "1" because your query didn't fail, to a certain extent.

Comment: In a database you shouldn't use float values for decimal values (until explicitly needed), use `decimal` or `numeric` since they store exact values, otherwise you could end with a price of `3.999999999998` instead of `4.00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(payment_price) as max FROM client_record WHERE payment_status ='Settled'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row['max'];
```

When you convert an `array` into an `int` it only converts it as a boolean value. Not the value of the `array`. So, use the index `'max'` to get the value you want, as you can see I edited the MySql query to add `as max` it will provide the value for `'max'`.

Comment: "When you convert an array into an int it only converts it as a boolean value" what do you mean by that? Casting array to int is undocumented behavior.

Comment: @ishegg I am not sure but the behavior does suggest that this is bool evaluation https://eval.in/876652

Answer (score 3):

As function you use, has a name `mysqli_fetch_array`, this means that result of this function is **array**. Casting `array` type to `int` type doesn't do what you expect.

Instead, what you need to use is just:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
print_r($row);
// what you need is something like
echo $row['MAX(payment_price)'];
```